# How to open UI in Linux

Tags: linux

In Windows, if I am on the command prompt (cmd), if I write the command

```
explorer .
```

It will open Windows Explorer with the current directory. Is there anything similar I can do with Linux?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`xdg-open .` opens with the default file explorer.

[More information is here](http://linux.die.net/man/1/xdg-open).

xdg-open uses data from

```
~/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list
```

(in most cases) to find the correct application.

The MIME type for a directory is `inode/directory` from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18869772/mime-type-for-a-directory).

Comment: not necessarily. If you only type xdg-open, it brings a minimal help, if you type "xdg-open .", depending on your configuration, it will interpret the dot differently, for instance, for me, it opens my user folder on firefox, which is not a file explorer.

Comment: @PatomaS it opens what ever is default for opening a folder. Which in your case is firefox. Thats your machines config. Lookup how to change it on your distribution

Comment: You are right, but since I haven't done anything to change it, which means, that at least in some cases, that command may not behave as you mention by default, so if you are not specially comfortable with the console, troubleshooting that behaviour doesn't seem easy. So I'm in trouble here, your answer is a standard procedure, which is good. I'll give you that point. But doesn't consider non standard configurations or help to really know your actual tool since they may think the explorer is xdg. Plus you have to pass an argument to the command ...

Comment: I tried to undo the downvote since you took the time to answer, but I can't unless you edit the answer, can you edit something ...

Comment: edited with more info

Answer (score 1):

On Ubuntu:

```
nautilus .   # For the current folder
nautilus /home/ # Opens the home folder
```

If you do not have it, just install this by

```
apt-get install nautilus
```

Then use the above command to explore the directory.

Comment: +1 Your answer is also working.. but permit to choose only one.

Comment: The other answer is the better choice, as it uses the user selected file explorer rather than a fixed one.

Comment: No you can open any folder,see the update

Answer (score 0):

It depends what file manager you have, but yes, you can.

For instance, type xfe, or dolphin, or gentoo, etc.

Type the name of the binary of the tool you want to open.