# MIME type for a directory

Tags: directory, mime-types

What's the MIME type for an OS directory?

When I attempt to detect a directory's MIME type using its content I get `text/plain; charset=utf-8` on Ubuntu.

Comment: I guess this is a general question - not OS specific.

Comment: see also android specific question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17165972/android-how-to-open-a-specific-folder-via-intent-and-show-its-content-in-a-file

Answer (score 27, accepted):

On Ubuntu, a directory mimetype is `inode/directory`

If you run, on Ubuntu:

```sh
$ mimetype /home/<your username>
/home/<your username>: inode/directory
```

There is a "text/directory" in the IANA standards (http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2425.txt and http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/text) but it was marked "deprecated".

Comment: FYI: On CentOS 6.5 `file -i /home/` yields `application/x-directory; charset=binary`.

Comment: `inode/directory` is what `.desktop` files use in the `MimeType` field to indicate that the application can be used to view directories.

Comment: text/directory is for a specific type of text file containing information in a key-value pair format not necessarily about files. It's primarily for a rolodex (eg: list of names + emails + phone numbers) but can contain other types of lists. It is *not* the type of a file-system directory. It is a plain text file editable in a text editor.

Answer (score 16):

There is no universal answer to this question.

Directories are not considered to have MIME types on Windows.

On Android, the directories exposed by a document provider are of type "vnd.android.document/directory" while those exposed by other content providers are typically of the form "vnd.android.cursor.dir/<something>".

On Linux, the [xdg shared mime info spec](http://standards.freedesktop.org/shared-mime-info-spec/shared-mime-info-spec-latest.html#idm140625828597376) dictates "inode/directory" be used for associating directories with applications.

Answer (score 0):

What I understand from https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6350 and https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2425#section-3 is that text/directory is deprecated for vCards only, it should still be actual for simple directories...

Comment: text/directory is for a specific type of text file containing information in a key-value pair format not necessarily about files. It's primarily for a rolodex (eg: list of names + emails + phone numbers). It's not for an actual OS file-system directory.